# passing data from BroadcastReceiver to class that extends runnable

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My goal is to create a method that gets the data from broadcast receiver and sends it trough a socket. I know how to send it, but how can i get a data from BroadcastReceiver ? I want to receive data in this class:

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable{
    Socket socket;
    public final String TAG = "CLIENT";
    ObjectOutputStream os;
    TextView text;
    Handler handler;
    AppHelper helperClass;
    Activity mActivity;
    Context mContext;
    public ClientThread(Activity mActivity,TextView text,Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         this.text=text;
         this.mContext=context;;
         helperClass = new AppHelper(context, mActivity);
         handler = new Handler();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            while (true) {
                socket = new Socket("192.168.1.10", 9000);

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        text.setText("Connected.");
                        try {
                            os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket
                                    .getOutputStream());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            text.setText("Output stream. smth wrong");
                            Log.i(TAG, "Output stream. smth wrong");
                        }
                    }
                });

                try {
                    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                            socket.getInputStream());
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = in.readUTF().toString()) != null) {
                        Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                        final String mesg = line;
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mesg.contains("getcontacts")) {
                                    try {
                                        sendContacts();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                } else if (mesg.contains("getmsg")) {
                                    getMessages();

                                } else if (mesg.contains("sendmsg")) {
                                    sendMessage(mesg);
                                } else {

                                    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO THE FRONT END
                                    // THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN BE CREATIVE
                                    text.append(mesg + "\n");
                                }
                            }

                        });
                    }
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            text.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                        }
                    });
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception x) {
        }
    }

    public void receivedMessage(String sender, String message) {

    }

    private void sendMessage(String s) {
        String[] x = s.split(" ");
        int lenght = x.length;
        String message = x[2];
        for (int i = 3; i < x.length; i++) {
            message = message + " " + x[i];
        }
        System.out.println(message);

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        System.out.println("sending message");
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(x[1], null, message, null, null);
        System.out.println("message send");
    }

    private void sendContacts() throws IOException {

        final List<Person> list = helperClass.getContacts();

        final String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
        Log.i(TAG, "lenght " + json.length());

        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    os.writeObject(json);
                    os.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e(TAG, "Sending Contact list has failed");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getMessages() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ProgressTask task = new ProgressTask();
        ProgressTask.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    List<Sms> sms = helperClass.getAllSms();
                    final String json = new Gson().toJson(sms);
                    os.writeObject(json);
                    os.flush();
                    System.out.println("List of messages send");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Sending Contact list has failed");
                }
            }
        });


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an interface as listener to this runnable.

1. Create a Listener interface
2. Declare Interface Variable in Application Context.
3. Instantiate and implement interface in Runnable class.
4. In BroadcastReciever, call method of that interface.

Ex:

```
Class A extends Application{
     public Listener listener;

}`

interface Listener{
    public void yourmethod();
}
```

In Your clientthread method instantiate listener as follows:

```
((A)context.getApplication()).listener = new Listener(){
    @override
    public void yourmethod(){
       // your implementation goes here
    }
}
```

In your broadcast reciever.

```
((A)context.getApplication()).listener.yourmethod();
```

Comment: That class A, as i understand is a new class ?

Comment: yeah it is called application class which can be accessed throughout app.
You may name it what ever you want. You need to add it in Manifest file also.